# Don't autorotate view controller, but show UIAlertView rotated

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad, uialertview, device-orientation

Is it possible to show a `UIAlertView` rotated to the device's current orientation inside a `UIViewController` that always returns `NO` in `shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can rotate the view after showing it depending on the orientation of the device, using this:

```
alertView.transform = CGAffineTransformRotate(alertView.transform, degreesToRadian(90));
```